# Validação checkbox dinamico com jquery-validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Estou tentando validar um `checkbox` utilizando o plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/. 
O problema ocorre que o campo que estou validando ele não existe até que um outro campo pré-determinado seja selecionado. Sendo assim, a validação passa mesmo sem esse campo existir.
Não consegui uma maneira de fazer com que a validação ocorra mesmo o campo não existindo.

Tentei assim:

```
$('#form_novo').validate({
 rules: {
    'bnd[]': {
        required: true
    },
    'responsavel[]': {
        required: true
    },
    'etapa[]': {
        required: true
    },
}
```

Esse campo responsável só existe depois de selecionado o campo `bnd`. Alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A única solução que me ocorre é controlares a existência desse campo dinâmico no `submitHandler` e agires em conformidade:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/g39Eb/)

```
$('#form_novo').validate({
    rules: {
        'bnd[]': {
            required: true
        },
        'responsavel[]': {
            required: true
        },
        'etapa[]': {
            required: true
        },
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // estou a assumir que tem a classe "responsavel"
        if ($(form).find('.responsavel').size()>=1) {
            form.submit();
        } else {
            alert("crap");
        }
    }
});
```

O que está a ser feito é permitir a submissão do formulário se o elemento dinâmico existir, caso não, fazemos algo como apresentar uma mensagem de erro no local adequado.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer com que o campo sempre exista, deixando o mesmo invisível?

```
display: none;
```

Se puder, então isso resolveria o seu problema.

Comment: Não posso, é um campo dinâmico que depende da escolha do bnd